# How to upgrade Magento 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.3.8 and security patch in localhost?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am beginner Magento developer. I have worked on Magento 1.9.2.2. How to upgrade Magento 1.9.3.8 and security patch in my localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty method I sometimes use for upgrades.  It is "dirty" because there are much better ways using version control and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

- Make a backup of your site.  Lots of things can go wrong.
- Download clean copies of 1.9.2.2 and 1.9.3.8 from [the release archives](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).  Extract them into sub-folders of your Magento folder, let's call them `old` and `new` for clarity.
- Check for a file called `app/etc/applied.patches.list`.  If it exists then download all those patches from the archive and apply them to the `old` folder.  That folder should now be a pretty good representation of your actual site without any customisations.
- Open a console (you are using Linux, right?), change to the Magento folder and run this command:
  `diff -ruN old new | patch -fp1`
  The `-f` option means 'force' and assumes common sense answers to any problems that might come up. Let's deal with the consequences of that.
- Now find all file changes that were rejected:
  `find -name "*.rej"`
  Manually edit each file listed and copy-paste the new code into place.  Rejects happen when a core file has already been altered and the patch program cannot work out what to do by itself.  In my experience this is more common with older, badly managed sites.  If you're lucky there may be none.
- Flush Magento's caches.  Upgrade scripts will automatically run and update the database.  Test all aspects of your site and restore from backup if it is badly broken, otherwise:
- Clean up temporary files:
  `find -name "*.rej" -delete`
  `rm -rf old new`